# Install MongoDB on Windows 8.1 64bit

Tags: windows, mongodb, windows-8.1

I'm trying to install mongodb on my Windows 8.1 64bit machine.

On the official website, there are only downloads for 2008:

- Windows 64-bit 2008 R2+
- Windows 64-bit 2008 R2+ Legacy
- Windows 64-bit Legacy

My questions:

1. What should I chose?
2. Why are there no options for XP, Vista, 7, etc
3. What does Legacy mean?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

see here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/

there is 64bit version, a 32bit version and a legacy version (vista, server 2003) - they are nicely explained on this page.

Comment: thanks, so for windows 8.1, chose Windows 64-bit 2008 R2+ right ?

Answer (score 1):

4.0.28 version of MongoDB can be installed in win 8.1 x64